# IE-11 Compatibilty Issues

Tags: compatibility, internet-explorer-11

I have a very old application, written of the time of IE-5. Some of the pages in IE-11 are not rendering despite having used the meta tag with ie=5 value.

I had this similar problem for making it work with IE-10 and the meta tag seemed to be working fine there.

Please provide your inputs on this ?

Comment: I want to congratulate you in advance if you manage to get it work :)

Comment: Do you mean to say that IE-11 has problems working with meta tag ?

Comment: I want to say that IE5 was built 15 years ago. I had major problems with site compatibility between IE7, 8 and 9 and it was my starting point for "hating" IE. Just making some fun, ignore it, I'll delete it if this become useful question.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the specific features that are failing, it's hard to say what might be the problem.

A number of features supported by IE5 are no [longer supported by IE11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn467852(v=vs.85).aspx), including ActiveDesktop, CDF, VML, CSS expressions, conditional comments, binary behaviors, and others.

The [IE Compatibility Cookbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/dn384059) is a good resource for this sort of thing; it summarizes  major compatibility changes to IE over the last several versions.  (There's also a page that contains links describing [minor changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn467846(v=vs.85).aspx) to the browser.)

One of the biggest changes is what happens when you load a page that does not contain a document type directive.  Prior to IE10, this would enable legacy (IE5) quirks mode.  Starting with IE10, it enables a [standards-based quirks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869300(v=vs.85).aspx) mode based on the HTML5 specification.

Unfortunately, there's no comprehensive list of all changes as that would be very hard to put together and maintain.  (Trust me on this one.)  But, [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/) also has a lot of useful information.

Hope this helps...